# Rails active record conversion of this sql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

> SELECT players.name, batsmen.* FROM batsmen INNER JOIN players ON
>   players.id = batsmen.player_id WHERE league_id = 13

How will I do this? I am using Rails framework and MySQL. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Player.joins(:batsmen).select('players.name, batsmen.*').where('batsmen.league_id = ?', 13)
```

Comment: player model didn't have league_id attribute it is in batsmen model

Comment: I have entered it on console this is what I am getting still no content from batsmen mondel

#<Player id: 632, name: "Aftab Ahmed", created_at: "2012-07-12 02:34:50", updated_at: "2012-07-12 02:34:50">, #<Player id: 633, name: "Mohammad Sharif", created_at: "2012-07-12 02:34:50", updated_at: "2012-07-12 02:34:50">


here is the description for both mondel

Player(id: integer, name: string, image: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

Comment: here is the content of Batsmen model 
Batsman(id: integer, player_id: integer, innings: integer, nout: integer, runs: integer, hights: integer, bestf: integer, sr: float, ave: float, hundred: integer, fifty: integer, zero: integer, fours: integer, siz: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, league_id: integer, match: integer)

Comment: use to_json at the end of query to see the model representation

Comment: yes it is show and it is accessible to but how and why it is not showing the data in console ...?